# jquery onclick if ...else if ...else not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Hi I am running an a jQuery function to send some data to an ajax request I have an if statement to get the active elements within a dropdown to pass the selection to the ajax request. Like so:

```
 $('#filters #region_dd ul.dropdown li a').click(function (e) {
    $('#filters #region_dd ul.dropdown li a').removeClass('active');
    $('#centre_dd > .active').text("Select a Centre").toggleClass('active');
    $('#centre_dd > ul.dropdown li a.active').toggleClass('active');

    console.info('Selected Region: "' + $(this).attr('href') + '"');

    if ($('.date-selection li a.active')) {
      date =  $('.date-selection > li a.active').attr('href');
    } else if($('#year_dd .dropdown.year-selection > li > a.active')) {
      date =  $('#year_dd .dropdown.year-selection > li > a.active').attr('href');
    } else {
      date = null;
    }
    var region = $(this).attr('href');
    filterData.update('/overview', region, null, date);
  });
```

However the else if condition is never caught even when that `.year-selection > li > a.active` is true if the `.date-selection > li > a.active` is active then this passed through. Any ideas what I've doing wrong with my else if??

Comment: may be because you are calling `.removeClass('active');` before the `if` condition

Comment: not on the .date-selection or .year-selection though @ArunPJohny

Comment: @ArunPJohny the first if doesn't fail but the else if does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem I can see is you are passing a jQuery object to the if condition, which is always truthy, so irrespective of whether there is an element matching the criteria `.date-selection li a.active`, the `if` block will get executed.

```
if ($('.date-selection li a').hasClass('active')) {
    date = $('.date-selection > li a').attr('href');
} else if ($('#year_dd .dropdown.year-selection > li > a').hasClass('active')) {
    date = $('#year_dd .dropdown.year-selection > li > a.active').attr('href');
} else {
    date = null;
}
```